# What is meaning of $X/P$? ($X$ is a set and $P$ is a partition)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

The definition of $x/E$ when $E$ is an equivalence relation is :
$$x/E = \{y\in X \mid (y,x)\in E \},$$
and the definition of $X/E$:
$$X/E = \{x/E\ \mid x\in X\}.$$
Now, what is $X/P$ when $P$ is a non-empty partition of X?

Comment: There is a natural equivalence relation associated to a partition: $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are contained in the same partition set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partition $P$ defines uniquely an equivalence relation $E$ by setting up

$$ (x,y) \in E \iff \exists p \in P (x \in p \wedge y \in p)$$

Then $X/P$ is just $X/E$.

Comment: Note that the equivalence classes of $E$ are precisely the elements of $P$. So $X/P$ is just $P$.

Comment: @MarkKamsma 
Is this true that type of $X/P$ is a relation but type of$X/E$ is a partition of X?

Comment: @Amir Both are notation for the same thing. But the type of $P$ is a partition, while the type of $E$ is a relation.